# Why does Socrative choose to keep the exponents separate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I had a Socrative problem

[image: socrative is dum]

Directions are to simplify. Answer is obviously c, because it is the only one with y in the denominator.

Why didn't they move $x^{1/3}$ to the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are choosing to "rationalize the denominator", as if $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers. If we have $x=2$ and $y=3$, for example, it's often nicer to think about $\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{12}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2^{4/3}3}$.